# ResourceNotFoundException in textview android

Tags: android, onclicklistener, calculator, buttonclick

Hello I'm quite new to Android. I developed a calculator which has all 10 number buttons and +,-,*,/ operation buttons.

But when I click the equal button it gives ResourceNotFoundException. Please help me with this.
Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero,add,equal;
    TextView displayVw;
    int btnVal=0;
    int total=0;
    int num1,num2;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        displayVw=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_display);
        displayVw.setHint("0");
        
        one=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        two=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        three=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        four=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_4);
        four.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        five=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_5);
        five.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        six=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_six);
        six.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        seven=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_7);
        seven.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        eight=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_8);
        eight.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        nine=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_9);
        nine.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        zero=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0);
        zero.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        equal=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_equal);
        equal.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String currentVal="";
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_1)
        {
            btnVal=1;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_2)
        {
            btnVal=2;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_3)
        {
            btnVal=3;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_4)
        {
            btnVal=4;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_5)
        {
            btnVal=5;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_six)
        {
            btnVal=6;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_7)
        {
            btnVal=7;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_8)
        {
            btnVal=8;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_9)
        {
            btnVal=9;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_0)
        {
            btnVal=0;
            displayVw.append(currentVal+btnVal);
            currentVal=displayVw.getText().toString();
        }
        
        
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_add)
        {
            num1=Integer.parseInt(displayVw.getText().toString());
            btnVal=0;
            //currentVal="";
            displayVw.setText("");
        }
        
        
        
         if(v.getId()==R.id.button_equal)
        {
            num2=Integer.parseInt(displayVw.getText().toString());
            total=num1+num2;
            displayVw.setText(total);
        }

    
    }

}
```

This is mylogcat

> 07-18 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 07-18 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
>
> ## 0x91 07-18 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1068) 07-18
>
> 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at
> android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4546) 07-18
> 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at
> com.chanaka.calculator.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:158)
> 07-18 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):  at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475) 07-18 09:21:08.930:
> E/AndroidRuntime(27409):  at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786) 07-18
> 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 07-18
> 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 07-18
> 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-18 09:21:08.930:
> E/AndroidRuntime(27409):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 07-18
> 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-18
> 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 07-18 09:21:08.930:
> E/AndroidRuntime(27409):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
> 07-18 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025) 07-18
> 09:21:08.930: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: in your onClick method you need to cast your currentVal+btnVal to a String

Comment: try with this line `displayVw.setText(total+"");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `String` to Set as Text in `TextView`..

## Problem is :

```
displayVw.setText(total);
```

## Correct Code:

```
displayVw.setText(total+"");
```

**Advice :**
*Cast every Integer To String before setting it into `TextView`*

Answer (score 2):

change

`displayVw.setText(total);`

to

`displayVw.setText(""+total);`

because when you write displayVw.setText(total) is to use text resource .

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
displayVw.setText(total);
```

to

```
displayVw.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 displayVw.setText(total);
```

by

```
 displayVw.setText(total + "");
```

You need to explicitly convert the int value to string because `setText()` takes String value. 
You can convert int to string by concatinating empty string like `int_variable + ""` or you can use `String.valueOf(int_variable)`. Hope this information is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to show total like:

```
  displayVw.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

instead of:

```
displayVw.setText(total);
```